# Fastest way of traveling between Berlin and Warsaw without using planes

Tags: berlin, overland, warsaw

Which is the fastest and economic way to travel from Warsaw to Berlin? Please exclude airline services.

Comment: Welcome! Best? Do you mean fastest? Cheapest? Safest? Most social? Cheapest? Well there's hitch-hiking, which a lot of our users do.  Please have  a look at the [help] on how to ask questions here, and then edit it to include more information, including what you've found so far, and then we'll have a bunch of people very keen to help you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [PolskiBus](http://www.polskibus.com/en/index.htm) bus it takes 9:30 hours and costs 15-26 EUR (62-109 PLN), depending if you buy in advance. It leaves ~3 times a day, isn't very comfortable.

Direct Euro InterCity train takes around 5 hours and costs around 54 EUR (230 PLN) for second class, around twice as much as the bus. If you buy in advance it can be cheaper, even 39 EUR as Martin mentioned. You can check the routes and buy the tickets on [Polish railways](http://rozklad-pkp.pl/en) or [German railways](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/index.shtml) websites.

You can also go by BlaBlaCar, it should take 6-7 hours.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to point that you can buy the train tickets also at bahn.de, where if you book the tickets well in advance they are also cheaper. It seems prices start at 39 € (at least that's the cheapest I could find).